# Sphinx search server: unknown type 'pgsql'

Tags: postgresql, sphinx

I'm trying to install Sphinx search server with pgsql and I have this error: "unknown type 'pgsql'; skipping;"

You will probably ask me if I have added --with-pgsql="path/to/pgsql" with "./configure" but I try to install sphinx with ... a remote DB!

So I can't specify --with-pgsql with "./configure" because pgsql files are not on this server.

My sphinx.conf file contains access to the remote DB (IP, database, port etc.).

If someone could help me on this problem.

Comment: You'll need to install the development pgsql files to build sphinx with support for pgsql.

Comment: So even if I have a distant pgsql I have to add pgsql files on the sphinx server? It seems strange to me! Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Thomas this isn't strange. Your Sphinx server has to know how to communicate with the remote PgSQL server. This is defined in the development pgsql files.

Answer (score 2):

check: **whereis pg_config**

must output: pg_config: /usr/bin/pg_config /usr/share/man/man1/pg_config.1.gz

if output: pg_config: *< nothing >*

then install package **postgresql-devel** (for SUSE) or **libpq-dev** (for other ver.) or another analog package